# Python Pandas Duplicate Header Row and Increasing File Size

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

I am writing a tool that will pull data from an API and save it as CSV. I want to run this daily and update my CSV, removing duplicates. Currently the data is pulled and stored fine, however I have two problems.

- There is a duplicate header row somewhere in my data that isn't being removed with drop_duplicates()
- If I delete the data.csv file and run the tool twice the data.csv file changes in size by ~5,000 kb and I don't know why

Here is the relevant code.

```
    def fetch_data_from_api(self):
        resource_dump_data = ""
        for idx, resource in enumerate(self.package["result"]["resources"]):
            if resource["datastore_active"]:
                url = self.base_url + "/datastore/dump/" + resource["id"]
                resource_dump_data += requests.get(url).text  
        return pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(resource_dump_data))
    

    def load_data_to_main(self, new_data):
        if os.path.isfile(self.CSV_FILE_PATH):
            existing_data = pd.read_csv(self.CSV_FILE_PATH)
            new_entries = pd.concat([existing_data, new_data])
        else:
            new_entries = new_data

        new_entries = new_entries.drop_duplicates()
        new_entries.to_csv(self.CSV_FILE_PATH, index=False)

def main():
    extract=Extract()
    new_data = extract.fetch_data_from_api()
    extract.load_data_to_main(new_data)
    print("Complete!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The images below show the change in file size and the duplicate header row:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/alyBL.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oGT9.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPhP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 1) fetch_data_from_api returns a pandas dataframe that is read from a csv file, and 2) this new data is passed to load_data_to_main() where it is concatenated with an existing pandas dataframe (which is itself read from a csv file). Concatenating these two dataframes (if they have the correct header) should result in only one header. Therefore, my guess is that one of the two dataframes (existing_data or new_data) must already have the duplicate header row when read in. If so, running "drop duplicates" won't delete the duplicate header since it would be considered a regular row (different from all other rows).

Is the api dump duplicating headers in the csv data dump?

If so, you could try reading in all csv files without a header (header=None) and then I believe dropping duplicates will result  in only one header being present.

Comment: You're right! The duplicate header row is coming through the API call as I'm looping over multiple data packages. How could I go about removing this from the resource_dump_data text?

Comment: One quick and dirty way would be to read the api data dump file without a header, then drop duplicate rows, then write the clean data back. For edxample,  df = pd.read_csv(<filepath>, header=None), and then df.drop_duplicates() should get rid of duplicate headers. When you write it back you can use header=False to avoid writing the "weird" index header you get. This is a dirty approach as it might be better if you try to make sure the api does not dump the header each time in the first place! (not sure how easy that might be).

Comment: Great advice I will see if I can make it work. You set me on the right path so I'll mark as solved. Thank you!